# Haml - Table missing ID

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm creating an email template with nested tables.  For some reason my ID is getting ignored in the nested table.  I tried both ways in haml (`#test` and `{id: 'test'}`), neither way will display an ID in the compiled HTML.  Classes show up fine.

```
%center
  %table.backgroundTable
    %tr
      %td
        %table#test
          /table has no ID
          %tr
            %td Test Test
```

Looks like:

```
<center>
  <table class="backgroundTable">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <!--table has no ID -->
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Test Test</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table>
</center>
```

Final question, where is the `tbody` coming from?  Should I explicitly be including it?

Comment: Have you tried Slim? (http://slim-lang.com/)

Comment: If you add a class before the id does it add the class?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, turns out it had nothing to do with Haml, there was a setting in Premailer to remove IDs

```
Premailer::Rails.config.merge!(remove_ids: true)
```